# keyword 'like' in my SQL statement in Poweshell is getting treated like an '=' sign

Tags: sql, powershell

The like statement in my SQL query in powershell isn't producing the intended results.  My 'like' statement is getting treated like an '=' sign.

for example

I have a table with the following values:

```
   FieldNames
1. George Bush;George Foreman;Mary jones;
2. George Foreman;
3. George Foreman; Michael Smith;
4. Mary Jones;George Foreman
```

Variable:

```
$Expression = "George Foreman"
```

Three options I tried:

1.

```
Select FieldNames from table where FieldNames like '%$Expression%'
```

2.

```
Select FieldNames from table where FieldNames like '%$($Expression)%'
```

3.

```
Select FieldNames from table where FieldNames like '%George Foreman%'
```

I receive the same results for all three options (only row 2 returns). I would expect all the rows to return.
I can run this same query in SSMS  and all rows return.

Has anyone ran across this problem or have any suggestions on how I can modify my select query to get all the rows using 'like'?

---

```
Formatted Powershell expression:

#Variables:
$Expression = "George Foreman"
$UserName = "UserName"
$password = "Password"
$Database = "Database"
$Server =  "Server"

$Query="Select FieldNames from table where FieldNames like '%$Expression%' "

$ConnectionString = "Server=$Server ;User ID=$UserName; password=$password; 
 Integrated Security=True; database=$Database;"

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

$connection.ConnectionString = $connection 

$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()

$command.CommandText = $Query

$result = $command.ExecuteReader()

$connection.Close()
```

Comment: Can you show more of the powershell?

Comment: Here is the powershell statement:  
$Expression = "George Foreman"
$UserName = "UserName"
$password = "Password"
$Database = "Database"
$Server =  "Server"
 $Query="Select FieldNames from table where FieldNames like '%$Expression%' "
$ConnectionString = "Server=$Server ;User ID=$UserName; password=$password; 
 Integrated Security=True; database=$Database;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connection 
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $Query
$result = $command.ExecuteReader()

Comment: Now edit that into the question, rather than a comment, so we can actually read and understand it.

Comment: Also: the **best** solution will be to change the schema design, so this column is in it's own table, where each delimited value has it's own row, along with the primary key from the current table. It's **NEVER** good practice to keep delimited data in a column.

Comment: Hi Joel, I have no control over the database design.  The database field values are delimited with a semi-colon.  The delimiter shouldn't impact the way the 'like' keyword extracts data.